# How do I get an SSRS chart to use a specific month or the last month for each year?

Tags: date, reporting-services, charts

I have the chart below in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 for an SSRS report.

The date in the x-axis uses January from each year, but I want it to use the latest month that is available from my dataset (from SQL Server). For example, we're currently in December of 2012, so I want it to be Dec-06, Dec-07, Dec-08, Dec-09, Dec-10, Dec-11, Dec-12 for the x-axis rather than Jan-06, Jan-07 etc.

I already tried reversing the order of the date in the SQL Server query (changed to descending), but it didn't make a difference to the chart (the data however is changed to desc, the chart just forces the date to have January).

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: The chart I have]

Comment: Have you thought about creating another dataset that just has that information?

Comment: No, that is not what I want to do. An image will help better describe the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing with the scale and iterations on the x-axis itself. Your data isn't going to change but you should be able to set this in detail.

**Updated Answer:**
You will have to live with setting the minimum on your chart to being x years prior to the current month this way forcing the month starting to be, say, December.

The following [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239363%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) specifies these minimum and maximim labels are automatically used. Then the intervals are set based on this. Your only option is to manually set the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion helped me get to the solution. I set the minimum to 01-MM-2006, where MM was calculated to be the latest month I had data for.